# What's the shortcut for opening home folder?

Tags: keyboard

Previously I was using windows in which we use <kbd>windows</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to open my computer.

So what shortcut for Ubuntu 14.04.I came to knew about the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal in Ubuntu. Help out with this.

Answer (score 14):

By default **Alt+Home** is the shortcut.

But you may change it to Super+E or anything like this if you want.

1. Go to System Settings.
2. Keyboard settings
3. Open "Shortcuts" tab.
4. Go to "Launchers"
5. Press on "Home Folder" and then press a key combination you want.

See here also: [maketecheasier](http://www.maketecheasier.com/useful-shortcut-keys-in-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 3):

You can actually use that same keyboard shortcut by making a custom keyboard shortcut.

1. Open `System Settings` and go to `Shortcuts and Gestures` or `Keyboard Shortcuts`. It should be near the top-right.
2. Under the `Custom Shortcuts` tab, click `Edit>Global Shortcut>Command/URL`.
3. Name the new shortcut `Nautilus`.
4. Under the `Trigger` tab, click the input box and type <kbd>WINKEY</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.
5. Under the `Action` tab type `nautilus` into the text box.
6. Save and close Settings and you should be done.

Tell me if anything can't be found. I'm using KDE right now, so things might be different. If something doesn't exist, I'll go into Unity to find it.

Comment: In the second step there is no edit option. But there is a + button in which it asks the name and command . what to do in it??

Comment: For the name, type `Nautilus`. For the command, type `nautilus`. @Akashgt

Comment: Thanks  for the reply man , muzzaffar's answer is more relavant to my computer.

Answer (score 2):

Press and the super Key(the key with windows logo) for about 3 seconds. This will show numbers over each item in the unity launcher.

[image]

Then the shortcut to open each of these items is <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>NUMBER</kbd>

By default the Home is locate under the dash directly then it will show number 1 then the shortcut will be:<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

Moreover when you open nautilus and you want to go back to your home then you can use the shortcut:<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>